# php open video using jwplayer upon select from input type file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jwplayer

I have html with a form and an input with `type="file"`. I'm trying to play an mp4 file after choosing the file with jwplayer before uploading it. I need to play video immediately. This is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#test2').attr('src', e.target.result);
                var fuData = document.getElementById('creative_file_video');
                var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;
                //   alert( FileUploadPath);

                playvideo( FileUploadPath);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }

        document.getElementById('asd').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

<input type="file" name="creative_file_video" id="creative_file_video" onchange="readUrl(this)" />

<div id="asd" style="display: none;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jw/jwplayer.js"></script>

<div id="player">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function playvideo(fileInput)
    {
        jwplayer("player").setup({ file:fileInput,
            image:"",
            autostart: true,
            height: 100,
            width: 100
        });
    }
</script>
</div>
```

When I load the page, the JWPlayer appears, but it shows the error text "Error loading media".

Comment: What isn't working? Are you receiving any errors? You need to add more details so that we understand what's going wrong.

Comment: jwplayer appears and says error loading media

Comment: That's a necessary detail. I've added it to your post, but make sure that when you post future questions that you add as many details as you can!

Comment: can you tell exact error it say, Is it  "Error loading player: No media sources found"

Comment: Please provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a random guess for the problem, you are facing since you have not given ful information I am going to go with my guess after looking at your code.

**please try below code**

```
    <div id="asd" style="display: none;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jw/jwplayer.js"></script>

    <div id="player">Loading the player...</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#test2').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    var fuData = document.getElementById('creative_file_video');
                    var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;
                    //   alert( FileUploadPath);

                    playvideo( FileUploadPath);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }

            document.getElementById('asd').style.display = 'block';
        }
           function playvideo(fileInput)
        {
            jwplayer("player").setup({ file:fileInput,
                image:"",
                autostart: true,
                height: 100,
                width: 100
            });
        }
    </script>
```

If that works then problem is as this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691275/1877909)

If error still occurs then check

If your player does not appear at all, please check if you:

- Uploaded jwplayer.js and included the  tag for loading
  jwplayer.js in the head of your page.
- Included a container  with an id attribute and referred to that
  id in the jwplayer(id).setup() call.
- Correctly formatted all options in the jwplayer(id).setup() call. We
  often see issues with commas, brackets or curly braces.

Check for more info [here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403682-troubleshooting-your-setup)