# JWPlayer - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Im wondering if someone could help me out.

Im trying to load a video using jwplayer but am getting errors.

This is the code im using.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("legacyPlayer").setup({
                width:370,
                height:240,
                file: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/legacy/videoname.mp4",
            });
        </script>

        <div id="legacyPlayer" align="center"></div>
```

The error my console is showing is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any help getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: try remove your last `,` in  `file: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/legacy/videoname.mp4",`  and also can you create fiddle including your external js file?

Comment: do you know what the error message means?

Comment: Im not sure what a fiddle is ... I dont know what the error message means, but when i click the error in the console it points to the first line starting 'jwplayer'

Comment: The div needs to be above the player setup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put script block after the HTML tag, looks like this:

```
<div id="legacyPlayer" align="center"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("legacyPlayer").setup({
        width:370,
        height:240,
        file: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/legacy/videoname.mp4",
    });
</script>
```

When browser document parser encounters a script tag, it will stop parsing the other html content on your page until the script is downloaded and executed. It means that "legacyPlayer" is not exist when you try to manipulate it in the script block. That's the root cause of "undefined is not a function" error (jwplayer selector can't find a DOM with ID:legacyPlayer).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was a very simple solution haha .. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your div id ="**container**" is equal to jwplayer('**container**') name

```
<div id="container">Loading the player...</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
        playerInstance.setup({
            file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-640.mp4",
            image: "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg",
            width: 640,
            height: 270,
            logo: {
                file: "//content.jwplatform.com/watermarks/gdz4zR4a.png",
                link: "//www.blender.org/foundation/"
            },
            abouttext: 'Video Available at Blender.org',
            aboutlink: 'http://www.blender.org'
        });
    </script>

</div>
```